# How to override compareTo Double method?

Tags: java, compareto

I tried to override `compareTo` method however I see compiler uses  `Java.lang.Double.compareTo` method instead of my `compareTo`.
What is wrong here and what should I fix and change so my own `compareTo` method will be used?

```
package GenerecEx;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;

public class ArraySort implements Comparable{

double val;
static ArrayList<Double> a=new ArrayList<Double>();

public static void main(String[] args) {
    a.add(2.4);
    a.add(8.4);
    a.add(9.4);
    a.add(4.4);
    a.add(6.4);

    sort(a);
    printList(a);

}

public static void printList(ArrayList a1)
{
    System.out.println(a1.toString());
}

static public void sort(ArrayList <Double> a1)
{
    for (int i=0;i<a1.size();i++){
        for(int j=0;j<a1.size()-i-1;j++){
            if (a1.get(j).compareTo(a1.get(j+1))>0){
                double temp = a1.get(j);
                a1.set(j,a1.get(j+1) );
                a1.set(j+1, temp);
            }
        }
    }

}
@Override
public int compareTo(Object element)
{
    if (this.val < (Double) element)
        return -1;
    else return 1;
}
}
```

Comment: There are too many problems with the code. For starters `compareTo` should be accepting `ArraySort` and not `Object`

Comment: It's because you are not sorting `ArraySort` objects means not calling ArraySort class compareTo method. In `a1.get(j).compareTo(a1.get(j+1))` statement you are fetching `Double` objects and calling `compareTo` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implementing the `Comparable` interface allows you to override the `compareTo` method *on the implementing class*. Having implemented `Comparable` on the `ArraySort` class, your `compareTo` method should actually be comparing objects of type `ArraySort`, not generic `Object`s cast as `Double`.